# Django Multiple many-to-many through

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I have two models A and B with an intermediary model C for holding a many-to-many relation using the `through`.
as extra fields in C can have different values for the two same related objects of A and B, is it logically OK to do that? 
i.e. pair of foreign keys to (A, B) in C to be not unique (Django do not create `unique_together` on them)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for multiple relationships between two objects to exist in your `through` table.  This can have surprising results when fetching related items, however, as `a.b_set.all()` will contain multiple copies of the item from `B` where there are multiple relationships.  If this is not desired, then you can use `a.b_set.all().distinct()` to remove the duplicate items.